# How to make a new column containing a time series from numerical values in other columns in the same row

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

```
library(seastests) 
        
paste_noNA <- function(x) {
      ts(x[!is.na(x)],frequency=12)
}
        
a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(2,5),c=c(10,2),
     d=c(9,22),e=c(6,3),f=c(5,7), 
     g=c(2,12),h=c(9,7),i=c(8,8),
     j=c(4,21),k=c(NA,7),l=c(4,2),
     m=c(7,3),n=c(11,8),o=c(7,8),  
     p=c(9,6),q=c(10,9),r=c(8,9),s=c("f","h"))
            
a$time_series<-apply( a[,c(2:18)] , 1 , paste_noNA )
```

> ```
> > a
>   a b  c  d e f  g h i  j  k l m  n o p  q r s
> 1 1 2 10  9 6 5  2 9 8  4 NA 4 7 11 7 9 10 8 f
> 2 2 5  2 22 3 7 12 7 8 21  7 2 3  8 8 6  9 9 h
>                                            time_series
> 1    2, 10, 9, 6, 5, 2, 9, 8, 4, 4, 7, 11, 7, 9, 10, 8
> 2 5, 2, 22, 3, 7, 12, 7, 8, 21, 7, 2, 3, 8, 8, 6, 9, 9
> ```

```
a<-a %>% mutate(iss=isSeasonal(time_series))
    
    Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `iss`.
    i `iss = isSeasonal(time_series)`.
    x Do not know the frequency of the time series.
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Consider the code above. I am trying to get in column "time_series" a concatenation of values in the numerical columns 2 through 18 treated as a time series. I then want to check the time series for seasonality, but I get the error as stated at the end of the code block above although the paste_noNA function has already converted the concatenation to a time series. Can someone help?

I also tried

```
a<-a %>% mutate(time_series=ts(time_series,frequency=12)) %>% 
  mutate(iss=isSeasonal(time_series))
```

but got the error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `time_series`.
i `time_series = ts(time_series, frequency = 12)`.
x `time_series` must be a vector, not a `ts` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `apply` function returns a list object, because "  the calls to ‘FUN’ return vectors of different lengths".

```
time_series <- apply(a[,c(2:18)] , 1 , paste_noNA)
class(time_series)
# list
```

I believe the error is due to `isSeasonal` expecting you to provide a `ts` object instead of list.

I would try something like

```
lapply(time_series, isSeasonal)
```

Comment: > a[1,20]
[[1]]
  Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1    2   10    9    6
2    5    2    9    8
3    4    4    7   11
4    7    9   10    8   isSeasonal is getting a ts object.